# Use Linq To Read From An Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, linq

How does one convert the following for loop into linq query to use `exampleDataList` and get the values out of it?

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("/") + "MyExcelFileData.xlsx";
const int startRow = 1;
IList<double> exampleDataList = new List<double>();
var existingFile = new FileInfo(filename);
enter code here
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
    var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();
    for (int rowNumber = startRow + 1; rowNumber <= currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
    {
        var col1Value = Convert.ToDouble(currentWorksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].Value);
        exampleDataList.Add(col1Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First change this:

```
IList<double> exampleDataList = new List<double>();
```

to:

```
List<double> exampleDataList = new List<double>();
```

There is no need to use interface instead of concrete type for a local variable. Then you'll be able to write:

```
exampleDataList.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(startRow + 1, currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row)
    .Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(currentWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value)));
```

You first create an enumeration with numbers from `startRow + 1` to `currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row` using `Enumerable.Range()` helper function. Then you project that sequence to something else using `Select()`. Lambda just mimic what you did inside your `for` loop.

If you're learning LINQ stuff I strongly suggest to take a look to [EduLINQ](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html) articles (from *our* Jon Skeet). They're well done and you'll understand many details about how it *could* be implemented.

**Edit:** as pointed out by rae1n in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165195/using-linq-to-read-from-excel-sheet/21165344?noredirect=1#comment31860608_21165344) if `exampleDataList` contains only data from this LINQ query (you don't need to add things before query) then you can use `ToList()` to convert enumeration returned by `Select()` directly into a `List<double>`.

Comment: If that's all the data in `exampleDataList`, you could initialize it with `ToList()`.

Comment: @rae1n you're right, I tried to keep original structure as much as possible but it may not be needed.